# Deduplicate mistyped shell commands

Tags: bash, shell

Ok, I can bet I'm not the only one that types `ssh` on the shell command, go look somewhere else what's the hostname, come back and type `ssh [hostname]`, which becomes `ssh ssh [hostname]`.

Then you just fix it, and repeat the same mistake with `cd`, `git`, `ls`, etc. later on. For years. Then decades.

I know one possible solution for that would be to have a hammer on my desk and use it on my hand every time I make this mistake; one day I'd have to learn.

But can anyone suggest a less painful way to solve that on bash?

I know it's possible to do that with `trap DEBUG`, but.. it seems so risky.

Only thing else I can think of is defining a function for each of these commands that checks the args.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? And regardless — just have a habit to check what you're press-Entering. Always. Specially when you looked somewhere interim. ;)

Comment: There could conceivably exist a host on your network that is called `ssh`, so `ssh ssh` _may_ not be an error. Correcting for this would involve writing a `bash` command line completion _thing_ that validates the hostname on the command line after `ssh` against the network _and_ against your SSH configuration file.

Comment: or a directory named `cd` or a file named `ls` or .......

Comment: Yeah! all those things could exist; but in the last 15 years they haven't existed for me. I'd be happy treating those exceptions as exceptions if/when they happen.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but a simple and fast correction method; just enter as your next command:

```
!*
```

This will repeat the last issued arguments as a new command.